# Windows Phone app sales - what to expect?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I realize that WP is not the main horse in the app race but I was wondering if this is the experience of others here.

I 'usually' develop for Android but thought I'd take a stab at the windows market. I took my most popular app, with 50,000 downloads on Google Play (4/5 stars) and an average of 90 downloads per day, and successfully submitted it to the WP market. Two days later, there have been two downloads. Myself and my buddy at work. Both downloads register on the WP site so I know the count is being counted. So I'm mystified as to why the literally 'zero' interest.

The app is in a class with few competitors and is free.

I don't get it. Anyone else see zero downloads of a Google Play popular app? Am I missing something?

Thanks all.

Comment: FWIW,  StackOverflow is optimized for programming questions, that is questions about code.  Since your question if more opinion based it not considered a good fit for the site by the community. I assume that's why you are seeing the downvotes and votes to close the question.  There is a http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/ site

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about sales from an app store, not a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably know there are many factors that lead to success in any app store.

Did you publish to U.S. market only?  U.S. market share for Window Phone is ~3.6%, compared to ~51% for Android.  Given those numbers you could only expect ~5 downloads per day.

How are you marketing your app?   What works in the Android world may not produce results in the Windows phone market.

The app category might make a difference.  From what I've read, Android users download more utilities than WinPhone and iPhone users.  Another issue could be that your app provides a services that is built-in to the WinPhone OS.

Anyway, those are a few thought I had when I read your question.

Comment: Thanks all - apologies for the 'off topic' issue.